# Problemas com WCF + Mysql

Tags: mysql, wcf

Quero utilizar esse método, localmente ele funciona e retorna o que quero, quando mando *IIS* simplesmente me retorna na última tela mostra o erro:

Dentro do *Service1.svc.cs* tenho esse metodo:

```
 public string envioPessoa()  {

        MySqlConnection conexao = new MySqlConnection("server='mysql.engb.uni5.net'; UId='engb' ;database='engb'; password='*********';");
        MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM usuarios AS r1 JOIN (SELECT CEIL(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM usuarios where TIPO = 'receptor' )) AS id) AS r2 WHERE r1.id >= r2.id AND TIPO = 'receptor' ORDER BY r1.id ASC LIMIT 1", conexao);
        DataTable tabela = new DataTable();
        string retorno = "";
        try
        {
            conexao.Open();
            MySqlDataReader  teste = comando.ExecuteReader();


            while(teste.Read())      
            {

                retorno = teste.GetString(2)+";"+
                teste.GetString(3)+""+
                teste.GetString(4)+";"+
                teste.GetString(5)+";"+
                teste.GetString(7)+";"+
                teste.GetString(8);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { 
           Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: '{0}'", e); 
        }
        conexao.Close();

        return retorno; 

    }
```

Na interface *IService1.cs*:

```
    [OperationContract]
    string envioPessoa();
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Certo você ja verificou se a maquina que tem o IIS tem acesso ao banco de dados ? ... não poderia perder não é uma boa prática utilizar o catch vazio ... tambem conhecido como pattern silenciator.

Comment: tem alguma sugestão do que colocar no catch?

Comment: algo assim poderia ajudar catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: '{0}'", e);
        }

Comment: Com relação IIS sim ele tem permissão e utiliza as bibliotecas necessárias.

Comment: Habilite os traces do WCF (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx). Sempre que um servidor WCF responde com um erro, uma entrada é escrita no arquivo de traces que indica por que o erro aconteceu.

Comment: Já habilitei mas não foi muito esclarecedor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeira coisa que fiz foi habilitar o servicedebug do web.config me basei nesse link [habilitar service debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315633/turn-on-includeexceptiondetailinfaults-either-from-servicebehaviorattribute-or), a partir dai verifiquei que versão do meu Mysql.Data era diferente do servidor instalei nele a nova versão e também adicionei ela na pasta bin onde foi publicado o serviço:

```
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
```